# How to view SQL table structure in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am connecting to Microsoft SQL Server using Oracle SQL Developer.

Describe table-name is not giving me any results. Can anyone please help me out with the right command to use to view SQL Server table structure in Oracle SQL developer?

Comment: Try `sp_help TableName`, it will show you the table structure.

Comment: If you are connecting to sql server you need to use sqlserver syntax (which does not have describe)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
--  custom table information
select  schema_name(t.schema_id)+'.'+t.name     as  TableName,
        t.*
from    sys.tables t
where   t.name = 'MyTableName'

--  table columns information
select  schema_name(t.schema_id)+'.'+t.name     as  TableName,
        TYPE_NAME(t2.system_type_id)            as  DataType,
        t2.*
from    sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns t2 on t2.object_id = t.object_id
where   t.name = 'MyTableName'
order by 1,
        t2.column_id
```

Or this:

```
--  custom table information
exec sp_help 'MyTableName'

--  table columns information
exec sp_columns 'MyTableName'
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for your answers. I have found one more method which is below

select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='XX_TABLE_NAME';

Thought of sharing as it might be helpful for others

Answer (score 1):

DESC is an Oracle client command - works in SQLPlus, SQLcl, and SQL Developer - WHEN connected to an Oracle Database.

The best we have to offer you is, open the table from your browser, and see the Columns page.

[image]

Or like someone has offered, write query or use the provided SP that MSFT gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Shift + F4

or Right click on tablename and click on popup Describe

[image]